# Issue of the edited message not being updated in the message component UI

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql

User
Here is my ChatPostDropdown.js

```
const ChatPostDropdown = ({
  show,
  username,
  messageText,
  time,
  messageId,
  currentUser = {},
}) => {
  const { globalRoles = [] } = currentUser
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(show)
  const [showDeleteConfirmation, setShowDeleteConfirmation] = useState(false)
  const [showEditModal, setShowEditModal] = useState(false)

  const [deleteMessage] = useMutation(DELETE_MESSAGE)
  const [updateMessage] = useMutation(UPDATE_MESSAGE)

  const isAdmin = globalRoles.includes('admin')
  const isAuthor = username === currentUser.username
  const canDeletePost = isAuthor || isAdmin
  const canEditPost = isAuthor

  const handleDelete = () => {
    setShowDeleteConfirmation(true)
    setIsOpen(false)
  }

  const handleEditCancel = () => {
    setShowEditModal(false)
  }

  const handleEdit = () => {
    setShowEditModal(true)
    setIsOpen(false)
  }

  const handleDeleteConfirmation = async () => {
    try {
      await deleteMessage({
        variables: {
          messageId,
        },
        update: cache => {
          const cacheKey = cache.identify({
            id: messageId,
            __typename: 'Message',
          })

          cache.evict({ id: cacheKey })
        },
      })

      setShowDeleteConfirmation(false)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error deleting message:', error)
    }
  }

  const handleEditConfirmation = async editedMessage => {
    try {
      await updateMessage({
        variables: {
          messageId,
          content: editedMessage,
        },
        update: (cache, { data: { updateMessage: updatedMessage } }) => {
          const messageCacheId = cache.identify({
            id: messageId,
            __typename: 'Message',
          })

          cache.writeFragment({
            id: messageCacheId,
            fragment: gql`
              fragment UpdatedMessageContent on Message {
                content
              }
            `,
            data: {
              content: updatedMessage.content,
            },
          })
        },
      })
      setShowEditModal(false)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error updating message:', error)
    }
  }

  const handleDeleteCancel = () => {
    setShowDeleteConfirmation(false)
  }

  const dropdownRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsOpen(show)

    const handleClickOutside = event => {
      if (dropdownRef.current && !dropdownRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
        setIsOpen(false)
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside)
    }
  }, [show])

  return (
    <>
      {isOpen && (
        <DropdownContainer ref={dropdownRef}>
          <DropdownMenu>
            {!canEditPost && !canDeletePost && (
              <DropdownItem disabled>No access</DropdownItem>
            )}
            {canEditPost && (
              <DropdownItem hasPadding onClick={handleEdit}>
                Edit
              </DropdownItem>
            )}
            {canDeletePost && (
              <DropdownItem onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</DropdownItem>
            )}
          </DropdownMenu>
        </DropdownContainer>
      )}
      {showDeleteConfirmation && (
        <DeleteMessageModal
          messageText={messageText}
          onCancel={handleDeleteCancel}
          onConfirm={handleDeleteConfirmation}
          time={time}
          username={username}
        />
      )}
      {showEditModal && (
        <EditMessageModal
          messageText={messageText}
          onCancel={handleEditCancel}
          onSave={handleEditConfirmation}
          time={time}
          username={username}
        />
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default ChatPostDropdown
```

and here is my Message component

```
const Messages = ({
  chatRoomId,
  channelId,
  fetchMoreData,
  queryData,
  lastViewed,
  unreadMessagesCount,
  manuscriptId = null,
  currentUser,
}) => {
  const { loading, error, data } = queryData
  const [openDropdown, setOpenDropdown] = useState(null)
  const [shouldScrollToBottom, setShouldScrollToBottom] = useState(true)

  const showDropdown = messageId => {
    setOpenDropdown(prevId => (prevId === messageId ? null : messageId))
    setShouldScrollToBottom(false) // Disable scrolling to bottom when ellipsis is clicked
  }

  const scrollToBottom = () => {
    if (!shouldScrollToBottom) return
    const main = document.getElementById('messages')

    if (!main || !data || !data.messages || data.messages.length === 0) {
      return
    }

    const { scrollHeight, clientHeight } = main
    main.scrollTop = scrollHeight - clientHeight
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollToBottom()

    return () => {}
  })

  if (loading) return <Spinner />
  if (error) return <CommsErrorBanner error={error} />

  const messages = sortAndGroupMessages(data.messages.edges, lastViewed)

  const { hasPreviousPage } = data.messages.pageInfo

  const DateWithUnreadLabelElement = ({ message }) => (
    <UnreadLabelContainer>
      <UnreadLabel>
        Unread messages:{' '}
        {convertTimestampToDateWithoutTimeString(new Date(message.created))}
      </UnreadLabel>
    </UnreadLabelContainer>
  )

  const DateLabelElement = ({ message }) => (
    <DateLabelContainer>
      <DateLabel>
        {convertTimestampToDateWithoutTimeString(new Date(message.created))}
      </DateLabel>
    </DateLabelContainer>
  )

  const UnreadLabelElement = () => (
    <UnreadLabelContainer>
      <UnreadLabel>Unread messages</UnreadLabel>
    </UnreadLabelContainer>
  )

  const renderChatPostDropdown = message => {
    if (openDropdown === message.id) {
      return (
        <ChatPostDropdown
          currentUser={currentUser}
          messageId={message.id}
          messageText={message.content}
          show
          time={convertTimestampToTimeString(message.created)}
          username={message.user.username}
        />
      )
    }

    return null
  }

  return (
    <MessagesGroup
      id="messages"
      style={{ paddingBottom: unreadMessagesCount !== 0 ? '20px' : '8px' }}
    >
      {manuscriptId ? <VideoChat manuscriptId={manuscriptId} /> : ''}
      {chatRoomId ? <VideoChat manuscriptId={chatRoomId} /> : ''}
      {hasPreviousPage && (
        <NextPageButton
          fetchMore={() => fetchMoreData()}
          isFetchingMore={false}
        >
          Show previous messages
        </NextPageButton>
      )}
      {messages && !messages.length && (
        <Placeholder>
          No discussion for this manuscript yet. Start by typing a message
          below.
        </Placeholder>
      )}
      {messages.map(group => {
        const initialMessage = group[0]

        if (initialMessage.type === 'dateWithUnreadLabel') {
          return <DateWithUnreadLabelElement message={initialMessage} />
        }

        if (initialMessage.type === 'unreadLabel') {
          return <UnreadLabelElement />
        }

        if (initialMessage.type === 'dateLabel') {
          return <DateLabelElement message={initialMessage} />
        }

        return (
          <MessageGroupContainer key={initialMessage.id}>
            {group.map((message, index) => (
              <Message key={message.id}>
                <GutterContainer>
                  {index === 0 && <UserAvatar user={message.user} />}
                </GutterContainer>
                <InnerMessageContainer>
                  {index === 0 && (
                    <Byline>
                      {message.user.username}
                      <div className="message-time">
                        <Time>
                          {convertTimestampToTimeString(message.created)}
                        </Time>
                        <Ellipsis onClick={() => showDropdown(message.id)} />
                        {renderChatPostDropdown(message)}
                      </div>
                    </Byline>
                  )}
                  <Bubble>
                    <MessageRenderer message={message} />
                    {index !== 0 && (
                      <>
                        <InlineTime className="message-timestamp">
                          {convertTimestampToTimeString(message.created)}
                        </InlineTime>
                        <Ellipsis
                          className="message-ellipsis"
                          onClick={() => showDropdown(message.id)}
                        />
                        {renderChatPostDropdown(message)}
                      </>
                    )}
                  </Bubble>
                </InnerMessageContainer>
              </Message>
            ))}
          </MessageGroupContainer>
        )
      })}
    </MessagesGroup>
  )
}

Messages.propTypes = {
  channelId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}
export default Messages
```

After editing a message using the EditMessageModal and clicking the save button, the message is successfully updated in the backend, but the UI in the Message component is not reflecting the changes until the page is refreshed. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GraphQL, react-query, and anything else that fetching server state, You should update your local data after mutate server state.

For GraphQL, follow below link.

> https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#refetching-queries

Comment: Hey @pedogunu I guess I did similar approach in`handleEditConfirmation` you can check the code

Comment: @ShubhamBelwal You should use cache id not data id in `writeFragment`. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#writefragment

Comment: I updated the changes please have a look at the `handleEditConfirmation` function still my message component is not updated.

Comment: I guess the main issue is page is not refreshed after clicking on the save button in edit model.

Comment: No. you should see the docs meticulously. [This comment](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/7756#issuecomment-786197256) shows why you use `cache.modify`. And [This link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#the-update-function) shows correct example. Follow this links.